# Can't get current user with Firebase Auth + Firebase Firestore

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm planning to use repository to get the data of logged in users in Firebase.

However, I am having trouble getting the correct user information because the user is loaded before the repository.

dashboard

```js
import { userRepository } from "src/repositories/UserRepository";

const user = userRepository.findById();
// user is <Promise....
```

repositories/userReposirtoy.ts

```
  async findById(): Promise<User | null> {
    // Authenticate with Firebase Auth
    const currentUser = await auth.currentUser;
    if (!currentUser) {
      return null;
    }
    // Fetch user data by Firestore
    const doc = await this.doc(currentUser.uid).get();
    const data = doc.data();
    if (!doc.exists || !data) {
      return null;
    }
    console.log("data", (doc.id, data));
    // correct user data
    return (doc.id, data) as User;
  }
```

User Type

```
export interface User {
  id: string;
  email: string;
  name: string;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you already store user data in Firestore? That doesn't happen automatically, so unless you already stored it there elsewhere in your app, `this.doc(currentUser.uid)` will not exist. If the document exists, can you show a screenshot of the document in the Firebase console?

Comment: The DB is indeed saved. So, I can get the data in the respository. The correct data for user cannot be retrieved because of the order of the calls.

Comment: "because of the order of the calls" Can you clarify? Keep in mind: we only know what you tell us about what isn't working, so we can better help you if you tell (or better yet: show) us what you learned from debugging the code already.

Comment: I'm really sorry. I am going to try to re-write this issue. Also, thank you so much for all your support!